# Return Database.SaveResult when allOrNone is set to true

Tags: apex, database.insert

I have a specific use case where I would like to insert records with:

```
List<Database.SaveResult> srList = Database.insert(contacts, true);
```

But also to get that SaveResult returned and to be able to iterate through that object to log failures for each record separately.

When `allOrNone` parameter is set to true and if any of the records fail then `Database.insert()` will throw an exception and roll back the transaction. I want to keep the default functionality of rolling back the records, but also want the ability to iterate through results and pinpoint the exact records that failed.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DmlException` has the information you're looking for, just in a different format. In other words, `allOrNone` being **true** doesn't give you the `Database.SaveResult[]` values, but this information is still available in the exception itself:

```
try {
  insert contacts;
} catch(DmlException e) {
  for(Integer index = 0; index < e.getNumDml(); index++) {
    System.debug('Contact at '+ e.getDmlIndex(index) + ' failed to save.');
    System.debug('The error was '+e.getDmlMessage(index));
    System.debug('The error type was '+ e.getDmlType(index));
  }
}
```

And so on.

The exception is slightly more efficient, though, as it only returns the exception rows, so you don't need to check `isSuccess` for every row, as you'd have to do with a `SaveResult[]`.

You can, however, use `allOrNone` set to **false**, and then use a `SavePoint` to manually roll back any changes to the database up to that point:

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(contacts, false);
if(anyErrorsIn(results)) {
  Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

Comment: sfdcfox, you never dissapoint, thank you!